# UTF-8 string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, utf-8, character-encoding, ruby-1.9.2

I have the following module:

```
# encoding: utf-8
module RandomNameModule

    def self.doesNothing(word)
        str = ""
        word.codepoints{|val|
            str << val.chr
        }
        return str
    end
end
```

and the following test:

```
# encoding: utf-8
require 'test/unit'
require '../src/RandomNameModule.rb'

class RandomNameTests < Test::Unit::TestCase
    def testDoesNothing
        sorted = WordSort.word_sort("£$&")
        assert_equal("£$&", sorted)
    end
end
```

When I run the test I get an assertion failure:

```
<"£$&"> expected but was
<"\xA3$&">.
```

This is because `"£".codepoints{|x| x.chr}` returns the value `\xA3`

how can I make this return `£`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Integer#chr`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9/classes/Integer.html#M000352) method used in your example seems to default to ASCII if you don't explicitely tell it what encoding to use:

```
def self.doesNothing(word)
  str = ""
  word.codepoints { |val| str << val.chr("utf-8") }
  str
end
```

Also, using `String#each_char` instead of `String#codepoints` works fine as well:

```
def self.doesNothing(word)
  str = ""
  word.each_char { |val| str << val }
  str
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I cant use each_char as I need the utf-8 integer value too.